# XOR two hexadecimal strings(unmasking) in C

Tags: c, websocket, hex

I wanted to unmask a hex string using the following algorithm in C
j = i MOD 4 transformed-octet-i = original-octet-i XOR masking-key-octet-j

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char masked[]="951bfdcdc113ebca921fe9dc";
    char masking_key[]="e17e8eb9";
    char *unmasked;
    int length=strlen(masked);
    unmasked=malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
       unmasked[i]=masked[i]^masking_key[i%4];
    }
    printf("%s\n",unmasked);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is \UT instead of 74657374206d657373616765. It would be really helpful if someone could help me fix the error here.

Comment: I think your strings should really be made up of hex char codes and instead of being hex numbers. So `"e17e8eb9"` should be `"\xe1\x7e\x8e\xb9"`.

Comment: You're xoring the ascii codes of the hex instead of xoring the actual numbers.

Comment: Aside: you allocated one extra but did not write a string terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from string format to raw integers before doing the XOR, then convert back before printing it as a string. Otherwise you'll XOR the symbol values, not the raw values.

You can convert the whole string in one go with `strtol(data, 0, 16)`. But one of the common details that makes programmers different from the code monkeys is the ability to code trivial string-integer conversions without the help of library functions. So here is a a simplified code doing just that - be aware of the complete lack of error handling, as this is just quick & dirty code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char hexlify (char nibble)
{
  return "0123456789abcdef"[nibble];
}

char unhexlify (char ch)
{
  if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
    return ch - '0';
  if(ch>='a' && ch<='f')
    return ch - 'a' + 0xA;
  return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
  char masked[]="951bfdcdc113ebca921fe9dc";
  char masking_key[]="e17e8eb9";
  char *unmasked;

  size_t length = sizeof masked - 1;
  unmasked = malloc(length + 1);

  for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
    char op1 = unhexlify(masked[i]);
    char op2 = unhexlify(masking_key[i%4]);
    unmasked[i]= hexlify(op1 ^ op2);
  }
  unmasked[length]='\0';

  printf("%s\n",unmasked);
  free(unmasked);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
74651cb3206d0ab4736108a2
```

Comment: (Since you are xoring nibble-wise, you should use `masking_key[i%8]` to get the expected output quoted in the question; read as pairwise hex bytes, it is a message in ASCII. Not sure where the `e` at the end comes from, either.)

Comment: @MOehm Yeah well this is just a fix to the OP's original code. The extra output was from a missing null terminator bug that I had fixed but I forgot to update the output in the post :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It was really dumb of me to treat strings in C the same way I treat them in python :).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is not xoring the hexadecimal bytes, but xoring the characters representing them.

While the ideal process would be `(0x95 ^ 0xe1) + (0xbf ^ 7e) + ...`, what you're doing is xoring the ascii values of each character, meaning `('9' ^ 'b') + ('5' ^ '1') + ...`.

What you need to do is first transform the hexadecimal string to the bytes themselves (`bytes.fromhex("951bfdcdc113ebca921fe9dc")` in python), and only then XOR them. The way I would do that is with `sscanf("%2x", ...)`.

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0;
    scanf("%2hhx", &a);
}
```